# Google Cloud Implied Firewall Rule Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I need some clarification on an "implied allow egress rule" that is documented here https://cloud.google.com/firewall/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules

This egress rule states it allows "any instance send traffic to any destination". Given that Google Cloud firewall is stateful, does that also mean that the appropriate inbound should be allowed as well ? This clearly does not work this way and I am trying to understand what the purpose of this rule actually is.

Comment: By default, all egress traffic is allowed. You do not need to create an ingress rule for egress traffic. Also, do not configure egress rules unless you know what the impact of restricting egress traffic is.

Comment: Strange, it only works in our environment when we add an ingress rule.

Comment: Edit your post and provide details on the VPC firewall rules and the connection in question.

Answer (score 1):

When a connection is established successfully between source & destination, it sends the traffic(request) through the established connection and will receive the response from the same and this is termed as Stateful firewall  but here  Implied egress rule allows any instance to send traffic to any destination but it does not allow inbound traffic as per stateful firewall because there is another rule called implied deny ingress rule  which does not allow inbound traffic. These implied rules are applicable by default and the main purpose of this rule is to segregate the inbound and outbound traffic. Inbound traffic must be explicitly allowed by separate firewall rules.

These defaults should not be considered appropriate or secure for sensitive environments. As John Hanley suggested, understanding what these defaults are is important when trying to level set the desired security posture you’re trying to achieve to align with technical requirements.